# Cousin/Brother(?) of Sherlock Holmes works to thwart an alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I'm searching for a short story where main character was cousin or brother of Holmes but he was genial thief instead. In this story he accidentally discovers an alien invasion taking place and he and his assistant try to stop the invasion

I'm pretty sure that story was written before 1985 was (approx) 30-40 pages long.

Answer (score 7):

Possibly "The Problem of the Sore Bridge – Among Others" by Philip José Farmer writing as Harry Manders

I've not read it, but a relative of Holmes who is a thief made me think of the character A J Raffles (invented by E. W. Hornung who was Conan Doyle's brother in law) who is often presented as a relative of Holmes in other works by later authors

The [Wikipedia entry on Raffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._J._Raffles) mentions this story in the section Other appearances -> Raffles and Holmes

Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raffles_stories_and_adaptations):

> Philip José Farmer put Raffles and Manders into a science-fictional situation in his story, "The Problem of the Sore Bridge – Among Others", in which he and Bunny solve three mysteries unsolved by Sherlock Holmes and save humanity from alien invasion

Note that the character Harry "Bunny" Manders appears in the Raffles stories as a sort of Watson to Raffles' Holmes.

In the quote above "Manders" and "Bunny" refer to this character and [Philip José Farmer](http://www.pjfarmer.com/WORKS-series-fictional.html) appears to have released this story using the  pseudonym Harry Manders

Comment: thx I think that be right answer :)

Comment: @RobKrol: Should you return, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.